# My winform app still running in the background even though I closed the app

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Like what the title said, my WinForm app will still runs in the background after I closed the app. I already put the below into my coding:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

But when I close the app by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, then I check the processes inside the task manager, it still running.

Is it that `FormClosing()` is not run if I close the app by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>?

Comment: Are you using a timer or backgroundworker? I had this effect when a timer I've set up was still triggering repeatingly because I did not deactivate it on form close.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have some threads that are still running and are preventing the program from closing.

I use the function to check if the threads are still alive:

```
  int maxLoops = 100;
  bool oneIsBusy = true;
  while (maxLoops-- > 0 && oneIsBusy)
  {
         oneIsBusy = false;
         Thread.Sleep(100);
         Application.DoEvents();
         foreach (Thread thread in ThreadList)
         {
              oneIsBusy |= thread.IsRunning;
         }
    }
```

You should keep a log on each thread and then wait for them to close. 
`Application.Exit()` should not be called in the `FormClosing` as it will be called anyway.

Comment: So, I put your function inside FormClosing?

Comment: I've try to put your function inside the FormClosing but there's an error for ThreadList. Error message: The name ThreadList does not exist in the current context. So I think my app does not run threads.

Comment: This thread list should be managed by you. You could use:


   ProcessThreadCollection currentThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;

foreach (ProcessThread thread in currentThreads)    
{
   if(thread != Threads.CurrentThread)
   { oneIsBusy |= thread.IsRunning;}
}